# C# - Server side WebMethod returns large byte[] as null to client

Tags: c#, asp.net, webmethod, pagemethods, maxrequestlength

I have a server-side ASP.NET WebMethod (System.Web.Services.WebMethod). It is called from the client via JavaScript. It uses System.Net.WebClient to download an SSRS report via its URL, converts the report to a byte array and passes it back to the client. This works fine for reports that are up to 11,089,998 bytes, but anything over that (say, 11,089,999 bytes) returns a null value to the JavaScript. I need to return a report that is 11,711,711 bytes, and will probably increase, but up to no more than 13 MB.

In the Web.config, I have:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="2097151" executionTimeout="3600"/>
</system.web>

<system.web.extensions>
  <scripting>
      <webServices>
          <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483647" />
      </webServices>
  </scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
```

Here are the relevant lines from the WebMethod:

```
 [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
 public static byte[] DownloadReport(string opt, string type, string arg)
 {
     byte[] report = new byte[0];

     // Misc code to get the SSRS URL

     using (System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient())
     {
         client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
         byte[] data = client.DownloadData(url);
         string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(fileName);
         File.WriteAllBytes(path, data);

         using (FileStream fs = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
         {
             report = new byte[fs.Length];
             fs.Read(report, 0, (int)fs.Length);
         }
         File.Delete(path);
     }
     return report;
 }
```

And here is the JavaScript PageMethod call and callback:

```
 PageMethods.DownloadReport(opt, type, arg, DownloadReportCallback, ReportErrors);

 function DownloadReportCallback(results) {
    var bytes = new Uint16Array(results.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        bytes[i] = results[i];
    }
    var file = new Blob([bytes], { type: mime });
    // For IE10+
    if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
        window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(file, name);
    }
    // For other browsers.    
    else {
        var a = document.createElement("a"),
        url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        a.href = url;
        a.download = name;
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        setTimeout(function () {
            document.body.removeChild(a);
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        }, 0);
     }
  }
```

I have tried and tried but can't seem to get this to work for reports larger than 11,089,998 bytes. Does anybody have any ideas? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had instances where the webconfig didn't work and I needed to set it on the serializer in the method.

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

serializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue; 

return serializer.Serialize(response);
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks a lot, I appreciate it. I'd bump it up, but I don't have enough reputation apparently.

Comment: No problem, happy to help